# Flyway jdbc migration connection trouble

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, flyway

I have a trouble with Flyway JDBC migration: after executing all statements I'm trying to close DB connection with `conn.close();` method and I receive `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.` exception. When I check my database - all changes that I was doing inside migration are done, but schema_version table is not updated: item about migration wasn't added.
More details here:
In flyway.properties I have added `classpath:com/packageone/somepackege/database/migration` to `flyway.locations` section. Then I have created a class that will perform the migration: `public class V1_1_1__SomeImportantMigration implements JdbcMigration` and filled in `migrate` method like that:

```
 @Override
        public void migrate( Connection conn ) throws Exception {
            beforeActions( conn );
            veryImportantMigration( conn, getData( conn ) );
            afterActions( conn );
            conn.close();
        }
```

Thing that are done in `migrate` method are applied, but closing the connection leads to an exception.
Due to info described above I have such question: Why this connection is closed before it is closed by me? and by what?

UPDATE (stack trace):

```
    [ERROR] Unable to rollback transaction
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:820)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.rollback(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:837)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:96)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:273)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$800(DbMigrate.java:53)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:210)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:146)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.execute(PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.java:68)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLDbSupport.lock(PostgreSQLDbSupport.java:162)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.lock(MetaDataTableImpl.java:174)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:146)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1010)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1464)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.flywaydb.maven.MigrateMojo.doExecute(MigrateMojo.java:30)
    at org.flywaydb.maven.AbstractFlywayMojo.execute(AbstractFlywayMojo.java:600)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Unable to restore autocommit to original value for connection
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:820)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.setAutoCommit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:762)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:114)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:273)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$800(DbMigrate.java:53)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:210)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:146)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.execute(PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.java:68)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLDbSupport.lock(PostgreSQLDbSupport.java:162)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.lock(MetaDataTableImpl.java:174)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:146)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1010)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1464)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.flywaydb.maven.MigrateMojo.doExecute(MigrateMojo.java:30)
    at org.flywaydb.maven.AbstractFlywayMojo.execute(AbstractFlywayMojo.java:600)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Unable to release Flyway advisory lock
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:820)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:275)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:293)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.prepareStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:319)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:247)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.execute(PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.java:81)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.postgresql.PostgreSQLDbSupport.lock(PostgreSQLDbSupport.java:162)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.lock(MetaDataTableImpl.java:174)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:146)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1010)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1464)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.flywaydb.maven.MigrateMojo.doExecute(MigrateMojo.java:30)
    at org.flywaydb.maven.AbstractFlywayMojo.execute(AbstractFlywayMojo.java:600)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: you are saying they are done partially. Is there an exception you are missing? Can you provide logs?

Comment: You should not close that connection, it is owned by flyway.

Comment: @Korgen, I can share logs. Cocerning partially - it was just my mistake...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, can you share some documents where it is written? I just want to understand the lifecycle.

Comment: It is not explicitly documented (as the usual convention in resource-management is that "you close what you opened, except when explicitly documented otherwise"), but look at the example on https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#java-based-migrations

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , thank you for link. I have another question than: How it was working before? When I was developing this migration - I was closing connection by myself, so why no exception was thrown?

Comment: I don't know, did you call `migrate` yourself instead of through flyway? In any case, you could always try to look at the [flyway sources](https://github.com/flyway/flyway). You haven't provided all code nor the full exception stacktrace. A `connection.close()` should never throw a `SQLException` if it is already closed, so your real problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , `migrate` was called through maven command like `flyway:migrate`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , stack trace is quite big, so I have posted it [here](http://pastebin.ca/3949724)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , done

Comment: The stacktrace shows the exception occurs when flyway tries to do its own internal housekeeping, long story short, remove the `conn.close()` from your code (and if you do it elsewhere in the migration code you didn't show: remove it there as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not call `close()` on the connection provided to you by Flyway. Flyway uses this connection itself for other housekeeping tasks (including updating the version table), and closing it prevents flyway from working properly.